# Oracle enterprise repository usage

Tags: oracle, oracle-fusion-middleware

In my project there's a requirement to capture all the integration data like the services involved, its dependencies , composite name , interface name, partners involved etc at one place. 
I understand that OER is a service registry. My question is; can we fulfill the above requirements using OER or it will require some custom solution. Please suggest.

We are using SOA suite 11g.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Enterprise Repository is not a service registry. For UDDI service registry you can use Oracle Service Registry.

**Repository** this is a thing that contains entities themself.

**Registry** has only links to entities, i.e. Oracle Service Registry has a links to WebServices endpoints.

Oracle Enteprise Repository can contains links to services (and can work with Oracle Service Registry), WSDL definitions, XSD definitions, services descriptions and many many other assets. But it is a very cost software, do you realy shure that need it?